# select data that only columns whose names match a condition with a fixed column

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, rstudio

I have a r shiny application in which user selects some value and based on that a dataframe will be filtered. Filter takes place on column names. But I need to have a fixed column along with every selection.

```
output$fault_template <- renderDataTable({
    fau <-  fau[,grepl(input$su, names(fau)) ]
    datatable(fau[,-1:-1],class = 'cell-border stripe')

  })
```

Sample data:

```
A   B    C    D
-----------------
1  3      4    5
3  4      5    6
4  5      2    2
3  4      1    9
```

In drop down I have only `B,C,D`

If I select `B` in drop down I need to get

```
 A B   
-----
1  3     
3  4    
4  5     
3  4
```

If I select `C` in drop down I need to get

```
A  C   
-----
1  4   
3  5    
4  2    
3  1
```

Column A should be fixed with any result

Comment: Why do you use partial matching (`grepl`) while you're looking for exact matches? The normal way would be something like `fau[, names(fau) %in% c(input$su, "A")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
output$fault_template <- renderDataTable({
    fau <-  fau[, c(1, grep(input$su, names(fau))) ]
    datatable(fau[,-1:-1],class = 'cell-border stripe')

  })
```

By changing `grepl` to `grep` you'll get column indexes. Assuming that column A has index 1, then add it to the selection with `c(1, ...`

If column A has a column index that may change, try:

```
c(grep("A", names(fau)), grep(input$su, names(fau)))
```

**input Pattern**

If the `input$su` is a character like: "ASD GHG BVG JJJ" you need to convert it to a useful regex

Try changing:

```
grep(input$su, names(fau))
```

to

```
grep( gsub(" +", "|", input$su), names(fau))
```

This results in a pattern: `"ASD|GHG|BVG|JJJ"`. I am assuming that each three letter group is a column name

Comment: It is working...but I am getting an error `Warning: Error in grep: invalid 'pattern' argument`

Comment: The pattern is given by the contents of `input$su`, post an example of it.

Comment: real data will be like ASD GHG BVG JJJ etc